# Cassandra data modeling suggestion

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myns.mytable (
"id" text, -- unique id,
"inserted" timestamp,
"score" int, -- score
PRIMARY KEY (("id","score"), "inserted"))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (inserted asc);
```

> Do you think there is a better way to model this? I want to query
>   mytable on:

```
1. find by id - #use ALLOW FILTERING error
2. find by score - #use ALLOW FILTERING error
3. find by id and score - works
```

I just want to be good at querying the table to get objects by id OR score  range OR both. Do you think i should create a secondary index on score?

Answer (score 0):

As you put **"id" and "score"** both in the **partition key**, you always need to provide both ***(id, score)*** values.

While data modeling on Cassandra we always prioritize which query we are going to make from this table. And model table according to the query. In your case you need to query by, **(id)**, **(score)** and **(id, score)**. So it would be better if you change your table definition by keeping the **id as primary key**, **score as clustering key**. So that you can query by, **id**, **score**, and both **id-score** combined.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myns.mytable (
"id" text, -- unique id,
"inserted" timestamp,
"score" int, -- score
PRIMARY KEY ("id","score", "inserted"))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (inserted asc);
```

Now you can query all of the following:

> 1. find by id - #use ALLOW FILTERING
> 2. find by score - #use ALLOW FILTERING
> 3. find by id and score

Comment: How can i only query by score? ex: Select * from mytable where score > 10

Comment: `SELECT * from mytable WHERE score > 10 ALLOW FILTERING ` should work. @user1908559